# Bash - grep text inside XML tags that contain unique alphanumeric strings

Tags: regex, xml, linux, bash, grep

I want to extract the text inside these XML tags using grep (no XMLStarlet or similar tools, even though they would be easier). I have done this before with grep, but this particular case is a bit more complex. The tags contain a unique alphanumeric identifier with hyphens (a MusicBrainz ID):

`<artist mbid="eaefd603-84c1-4db4-a72b-0cb718a0cc07">Chelsea Wolfe</artist>`

I have tried this and numerous variations:

`grep -Po '(?<=<artist mbid=.*?>).*?(?=</artist>)'`

In almost all cases, I get a "grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length". In Perl, iirc, `\K` is a solution to that error, but I'm not sure precisely where to put that (I'm a regexp novice, in case you couldn't tell). I've been unsuccessful with simple trial-and-error.

I've spent a few hour searching SO and Google, and I couldn't find anything similar enough to be of help (possibly I missed something). So, my question is: Using grep, how can I extract the text in-between tags when those tags include unique alphanumeric identifiers?

Comment: Are the unique alphanumeric identifiers always the same length? (sometimes they are)

Comment: Yes, they seem to always be 36 chars (including hyphens)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `\K` ("keep out" -- drop what is matched so far), try

```
grep -oP '<artist mbid=.*?>\K.*?(?=</artist>)'
```

i.e. you put the `\K` after the bit you want to drop from the match.

Otherwise if you want to use the lookbehind:

If you do not expect a '>' to be in an artist's name, and you expect your XML to be well-formed (no mismatching tags), and you don't expect tags to be nested *inside* an artist, try

```
grep -Po '(?<=>)[^>]+(?=</artist>)'
```

Comment: The first one works perfectly. I had actually tried that, but with `<artist mbid=*?>` which returned nothing, so I assumed I had the placement of `/K` wrong. Thank you. The 2nd code example matches many other tags in addition to the ones I wanted to match.